# Monolog Logger error

Tags: composer, monolog

`<Irrelevent preliminary context>` Somewhere in the process not understanding modules and whether they get to have Variable classes, and running `php craft make module` and `composer dump-autoload -a` `</Irrelevant preliminary context>` I edited the main craft/composer.json and ran into troubles. Ended up nuking the vendor folder and reinstalling, but now I have this error, which I can't get rid of after many hours, and which seems to happen very early in Craft's initialization process:

**Type of craft\log\MonologTarget::$logger must be ?Psr\Log\LoggerInterface (as in class samdark\log\PsrTarget)**

coming in
`craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/log/MonologTarget.php` at the class definition of MonologTarget

Any suggestions other than a complete reinstall of Craft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for now you might try to downgrade :

- psr/log to 1.1.4
- samdark/yii2-psr-log-target to 1.1.3

this error cause of update `samdark/yii2-psr-log-target` from 1.1.3 to 1.1.4

based : https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/13963

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it.

Comment: For clarity, this is just a (hopefully temporary) bug in a dependency package which was introduced within the past 48 hours. With any luck, it’ll soon be fixed by the package maintainer (or patched within Craft itself).

Comment: Yup it's already fixed

Comment: This was fixed in Craft 4.5.11.1 https://github.com/craftcms/cms/releases/tag/4.5.11.1

Comment: How do I fix this? How do I downgrade samdark/yii2-psr-log-target?

I am unable to upgrade craft as this has already broken it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Anyone still looking for how to fix this, the answer is givin in the link above specifically the comment here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/13963#issuecomment-1830116976

> If you can't run php craft update because the incompatible psr/log version is already installed, you need to update to 4.5.11.1 manually using Composer. First, require that specific version of Craft with Composer:
> `composer require craftcms/cms:4.5.11.1`
> This will upgrade Craft to the specified version, which pins the psr/log dependency, so it will also downgrade that library to the supported version. After that, you can run php craft update again.
> Alternatively, if you're on an older version and can't update Craft for any reason, you can workaround this issue by explicitly requiring psr/log 1.x in your project:
> `composer require psr/log:^1.0.0`
> This will downgrade the package and fix the compatibility issue. Once you upgrade to Craft 4.5.11.1, you can remove the direct depency again.